# Internals of Java Exceptions

Tags: exception, jvm, java

The native method fillInStackTrace in the open-jdk makes a call **JVM_FillInStackTrace(env,throwable)** Is the source of this method not supplied?

throw is a jvm instruction *athrow*. Something similar to jump in assembly
Jvm itself is native code so anything implemented in the jvm is native too.So is **throw** native?
In other words **intrinsic call to fillInStackTrace does not incur the cost of a usual JNI call?**(and cost is of filling the stack trace)

**Is try-catch for cached exceptions guaranteed to work**? How will be the exception tables be filled.For the same exception there will me multiple matching catch blocks?

**Are they truly costly in a web application(or any with similar latencies)?**
Say a web service get/employee/{invalid_id}  throwing 
javax.ws.rs NotFoundException instead of using if/else to return a 404 response.
Considering the cost of http request,response and object-Json serialization/deserialization the cost of exception is not much.

Comment: Generally speaking, filling in stack traces is relatively expensive.  That may be tolerable for cases that should be rare in practice, but simple `if`/`else` logic will be _much_ faster if it's available.

Comment: IIRC, it's something like 95% of the cost of throwing a new exception.

Comment: *"Are they truly costly"* - there is no genral answer, benchmark your usecase.

Comment: Doesn't hotspot optimize out certain exceptions? the `try { Integer.parseInt("one"); } catch (NumberFormatException e) { }` variety?

Answer (score 1):

When an exception object is created, the stacktrace needs to be captured.  The JVM does this by walking the java stack to find all the methods in the call chain leading to this point.

The cost of the fillInStackTrace method is proportional to the depth of the java stack when the method is called.  The JNI vs intrinsic overhead is low compared to this cost.

Exception catching is independent of using a cached exception or a newly created one.  When executing the *athrow* bytecode, the JVM walks the java stack and looks for a method that can has a catch block able to handle the current exception type.

Exceptions are intended for **exceptional events** and should not be used for control flow.

Answer (score 0):

In practice exceptions *are* used for non-local control flow. For example jruby and scala (and possibly other JVM-based languages) use them to break in functional loop bodies or return on an outer function from closures.

But they use optimized ones that don't not fill in the stack trace and/or using pre-allocated exceptions, which the JVM optimizes into a goto if it can inline them. But those are specialized cases where no other options are available.

In the general case exceptions should only be used to signal exceptional behavior.
*Exceptional* can still mean *expected but uncommon* in cases that can be considered a slow code path where the exception-recovery is so costly anyway that generating the exception is a negligible price in comparison. Various network-related exceptions would be an example as networks are never 100% reliable but errors do not dominate the bulk of operations either.